# ¿Como hacer un buscador que busque en multiples columnas?

Tags: javascript, mysql, buscador

Estoy realizando un proyecto con phonegap, por lo cual trabajo en entrono javascript, html y css y trabajando estos datos de forma externa con PHP y MYSQL. Tengo un buscador realizado por ajax y que hasta ahí todo perfecto, me muestra lo que busco de manera correcta, pero el problema es que solo me busca por nombre, y quisiera que me buscase por el nombre y otro dato mas como la marca del producto.

Imaginemos que es Leche Entera el nombre, y la marca es Hacendado, pues que al introducir Leche Entera Hacendado apareciese, por el momento solo funciona buscando Leche Entera.

[image: Imagen del buscador (Instantaneo)]

El texto introducido lo envía mediante ajax al archivo php del servidor, y este le retorna los datos.

El PHP es este:

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$keyword=htmlspecialchars($_GET["search"]);
$data=array();
$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT products.product_name,brands.brand_name,products.product_price,products.product_size,products.product_image FROM products,brands WHERE brands.brand_id=products.product_brand and products.product_name LIKE '%$keyword%' and brands.brand_name LIMIT 5");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
    $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
```

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Y cual es el problema que tuviste, al agregar el otro campo a la query?

Comment: Lo que quieres es que tu "keyword" esté compuesto por varias columnas y que filtre exactamente según los criterios en el keyword, lograr algo así es complicado porque no se sabe qué parte del keyword corresponderá a qué columna. Lo común es hacerlo como dice @rencinas, tratando de buscar ese keyword en todas las columnas, aunque al buscar "leche entera hacendado" devolverá todos los resultados donde nombre = "leche entera" y marca ="hacendado". No hay una solución fácil a tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Si he entendido bien la pregunta, estás buscando con una misma palabra/filtro, buscar sobre diferentes campos de tu tabla.

La consulta SQL sería en esencia la misma, lo único que añadiríamos al `WHERE` más clausulas:

```
SELECT products.product_name,brands.brand_name,products.product_price,products.product_size,  
products.product_image   
FROM products,brands 
WHERE brands.brand_id=products.product_brand AND( 
  products.product_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
  products.nombre_campo LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
  products.nombre_campo2 Like '%$keyword%' OR 
  n campos) AND
brands.brand_name LIMIT 5;
```

Encapsulamos las diferentes columnas entre parentesis y con `OR` para que te traiga los resultados si uno de los campos por los que filtras coincide con el "keyword", si quisieras que coincidiera con todos, tendrías que sustituir el `OR` por `AND`